# How to remove a specfic pattern in string or remove array elements containing a pattern

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I am having difficulty figuring out how to remove some unwanted characters.

Below is a sample of my array data. I would like to remove all occurences of "Rail National" or remove elements containing the string "Rail National".

[image: sample array from need to remove text "Rail National" or part of this string]

Comment: Are you adding to the array via query or looping over some other data?

Comment: I am preparing array from an string using delimeter \n.
I tried using normal replace function but it will work, May be regex can be helpfull but I don't know well about regex, :(

Comment: Do you want to remove the entire array element if it contains the string, or do you want to just remove the text from the element.  What if nothing is left but any empty string after removing the text?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, this will completely remove any element from the array that contains the text 'rail national' anywhere in it:

```
newArray = [
  'Adult Child Class',
  'Ticket Type',
  'I rail national Rail Nation',
  'Rail Nationa',
  'Rail National',
  'Route']
// Remove items from the array
.filter( function(i){ 
    return !(findNocase( i, 'Rail National' ) > 0);
// Edit items in the array
} ).map( function(i){ 
    return replaceNocase( i, 'il Nati', '', 'all' );
} );
```

The filter function will run the closure against each item in the array and only return that item in the final array if the closure returns true.

http://cfdocs.org/arrayfilter

The map function will return the array with each item potentially modified.

http://cfdocs.org/arraymap

Note, you didn't say what CF engine you're using.  This sample code will run on Lucee Server.

Comment: issue is I want to remove some of text as well like "il Nati" "National" any substring can be come in array. It seems to me that ragex can be a solussion.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you want then.  Please edit the question to be more clear.  Perhaps providing a list of possible inputs and the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--- your data --->
<cfset yourArray = [

    "Adult Child class",
    "Ticket type",
    "Elk NIL StD RTN",
    "ANYTIME R",
    "Start Date",
    "Number",
    "I Rail National Rail Nation",
    "Valid unt",
    "Rail Nationa",
    "price"

]>

<!--- array for filtered data --->
<cfset filteredArray = []>

<cfloop array="#yourArray#" index="element">

    <!--- remove elements (by skipping) that contain "Rail National" (case insensitive) --->
    <cfif element contains "Rail National">
        <cfcontinue>
    </cfif>

    <!--- remove all occurences of substring "il Nati" (case insensitive) in element --->
    <cfset element = replaceNoCase(element, "il Nati", "", "ALL")>

    <!--- additional filters --->
    <!--- ... --->

    <!--- add/keep element --->
    <cfset filteredArray.add(element)>

</cfloop>

<cfdump var="#filteredArray#">
```

Comment: If you just chain .map( function(i){ return replaceNocase( i, 'il Nati', '', 'all' ); } ) to my code above, our examples would do the same thing, mine just being in script and simplified using higher order functions.  I actually started out with the map() but I honestly can't figure out exactly what it is the OP wants.

Comment: I assume the OP was asking for an approach how to handle this kind of data manipulation, thus I made it as verbose as possible. Also, since the OP did not mention the target version of CF, I proposed CF9 compatible code. Nothing wrong with your answer, Brad.

Answer (score 0):

A Regex version, as requested:

```
CR=chr(13);
myRegEx="(^|[\n])[^Rr\n]*Rail Nationa[^\n]*([\n]|$)";
myList=ArrayToList(myArray,CR);
myList=ReReplace(myList,myRegEx,CR,"All");
myArray=ListToArray(myList,CR);
```

A chained RegEx version:

```
CR=chr(13); 
myRegEx="(^|[\n])[^Rr\n]*Rail Nationa[^\n]*([\n]|$)";
myArray=myArray.toList(CR).ReReplace(myRegEx,CR,"ALL").ListToArray(CR);
```

A slightly shorter chain:

```
myArray=myArray.toList(CR).ReplaceAll(myRegEx,CR).ListToArray(CR);
```

Indented version - often preferred over one liners:

```
myArray=myArray
    .toList(CR)
    .ReplaceAll(myRegEx,CR)
    .ListToArray(CR);
```